# iOS keep status bar in portrait

Tags: ios

I have an app that uses the proximity sensor but the proximity sensor does not work in landscape mode. I have heard that if you keep the status bar in portrait mode it the sensor will work 
I have tried this but it did not work.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

The status bar still switched into landscape mode.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to keep your app in portrait mode regardless of DeviceOrientation, I would suggest you add the following code to your viewController.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

This will ensure that your app will start in portrait mode, and stay in portrait mode, even if the device is turned.

EDIT: In order to keep the app in landscape while having just one view on portrait mode, add the above code to the one viewController you would like to restrict to portrait mode.

Add the following function to your appDelegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    /* This is in order to allow views that do not support landscape mode to be able to load in
     */
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Add the following code to your other view controllers:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
        return YES;
    }
    - (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    - (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; //you can choose either landscape orientation here
    }
```

I suggest you use this hierarchy:

- RootViewController - it will contain the reference (preferably
  strong) to your proximity sensor, which I recommend you run on a
  background thread. This will support only portrait mode, so your
  proximity sensor will work ok (I hope).
- displayViewController - it will contain all the UI elements you have, and support only landscape mode
- You could manage communication between both of them by using delegates

Also, after the viewDidApper of RootViewController, please use the presentViewController (iOS 6.0 and above) or presentModalViewController (iOS 5.x) selector to add the displayViewController's view on screen. Using `[self.view addSubview: displayViewController.view];` will not work (I speak from personal experience).

Comment: This is, of course, assuming that you are using iOS 6.0 or above

Comment: Thanks, but my app is built for landscape mode, so if it is in portrait mode then it will mess everything up.

Comment: If I use this, will that view be completely in portrait mode. Because the all views of the app were designed for landscape and if the view is in portrait that is fine but I don't want the objects in the view to move at all.

Comment: If you use presentViewController (iOS 6.0 and above), it should be fine. Your rootViewController will always stay in portrait, but your displayViewController will respond to landscape left and landscape right. Be sure to set up a delegate so that proximity sensor information and UI events can be transferred between the two view controllers. (PS: I made an error with the answer, it is presentViewController, not pushViewController - edited it already)

Comment: So the objects on my view will not move or be changed in any way?

Comment: No. I tried a similar thing on the iPhone, which had a rootViewController restricted to portrait, but it called out a camera. The cameraViewController could respond to portrait, landscape right and landscape left, without any problem, even though its rootViewController had a restriction to just portrait.

Comment: Ok good, I will try it. But why did apple make it that the proximity sensor does not work in landscape? like its weird and annoying.