# Fix Status Bar even in Landscape

Tags: objective-c, rotation, statusbar, landscape, portrait

I have a ViewController inside a UINavigationController and only this navigationController in my app is in portrait. So i forced it to be
always in portrait implementing in my NavigationController the following methods:

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
  }
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
  }

So it works to force my NavigationController be always in portrait programmatically. But when a change to landscape in simulator my status bar disappear. I want to keep my status bar appearing in portrait mode even if i change it to landscape ( its not a landscape at all, it is a rotation ). 
I've tried a lot of things with no result.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184641/ios-keep-status-bar-in-portrait

Comment: Yes but it also didn't work. =/

Comment: It did not work for me either.